# About depth and regular sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a local Noetherian ring with $\text{depth}(A) = 2$. This means, we can find out two elements $a$ and $b$ in the maximal ideal which form a regular sequence. Now, given $x\in A$, an $A$-regular element, can we find out another element, say $y\in A$, such that $x, y$ form a regular sequence?

*P.S.* We can generalize this question to $\text{depth}(A) = s$ and given a regular sequence with $r \lt s$ elements, and then to ask the same question to find out the remaining $s-r$ elements.

Comment: [This](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LE) might be helpful. Also, here is a [tutorial for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is really simple: if $m$ is contained in the set of zero divisors of $A/xA$ then depth A = 1.

Comment: @user26857 thanks a lot dears!

Comment: @Krish thanks a lot dear